# Fragment cannot be loaded in google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to run an app using Google maps v2, but the Logcat shows the error:

Fatal exception: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.mapa/com.app.MapaLugares}: android.view.InflatException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is the code:

activity_mapa_lugares.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

MapaLugares.java

```
package com.app.mapa;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MapaLugares extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa_lugares);

 mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById (R.id.mapa)).
     getMap();

 mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
      Projection proj = mMap.getProjection();
      Point coord = proj.toScreenLocation(point);

              Toast.makeText(MapaLugares.this, "Click\n" + "Lat: " + 
              point.latitude + "\n" + "Lng: "+ point.longitude+ "\n" + "X: "    
              + coord.x + " - Y: "+ coord.y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
              .show();
        }

    });

}   

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mapa_lugares, menu);
  return true;
}
```

}

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you noticed what it states in the MapFragment.getMap documentation? _Returns the GoogleMap. Null if the view of the fragment is not yet ready_. EDIT: Also, you're fetching fragment with ``mapa`` id while layout contains ``+id/map``.

Comment: There are more than one problems. Paste complete stack of your error.

Comment: Please paste **the entire stack trace**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your map in the XML file to be of type: `SupportMapFragment`:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

But in your java code you are trying to get another object:

```
 mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById (R.id.mapa)).
 getMap();
```

**2 Problems here:**

**1.** You need to fetch the `SupportMapFragment` and not `MapFragment`, like so:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

**2.** You are trying to get the wrong id: in XML you gave the map the: `android:id="@+id/map"

while in code you are trying to get: `(R.id.mapa)` and this is the wrong id.

Fix those issues and tell us what is the result.

You can also go over this blog post I wrote on Google Map API V2 to get a better idea on how to build an application that uses Google Map API V2:

[Google Map API V2 guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed what you told me and everything runs now except maps are not displayed on the screen. I only see the screen blank and I don't know why. I read your blog and I checked all the steps but maps are not displayed.

Comment: what was the step that fixed your issue?

Comment: The problem was the API Key, that it was wrong. I don't know why, but sometimes the API Key created doesn't run and you must change it.

Comment: yes, I had this issue once too. needed to delete the dubug.keystore and register a new produced key.